# Getting header.append is not a function in setting auth using Apollo angular example

Tags: angular, apollo-client

I'm implementing a module based on the apollo angular recipe shown here:

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/recipes/authentication.html

However in my case I'm getting an error because the `headers` parameter does not have an append function (it looks like it has some options like forceFetch and cache).  Should I just initialize an empty {} for headers when it is null - and does that mean the example they are showing is incorrect?  ... Or am I doing something wrong?

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Apollo } from 'apollo-angular';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-angular-link-http';
import { setContext } from 'apollo-link-context';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';

@NgModule({ ... })
export class GraphQLModule {
  constructor(
    apollo: Apollo,
    httpLink, HttpLink
  ) {
    const http = httpLink.create({uri: '/graphql'});

    const auth = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
      // get the authentication token from local storage if it exists
      const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
      // return the headers to the context so httpLink can read them
      // in this example we assume headers property exists
      // and it is an instance of HttpHeaders
      if (!token) {
        return {};
      } else {
        return {
          headers: headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
        };
      }
    });

    apollo.create({
      link: auth.concat(http),
      // other options like cache
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: You are using HttpHeaders, then I suppouse you want to say {headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`). In Angular5 things changed. see https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 0):

I'd encountered the same issue before. I'd successfully passed the authorization header by directly putting it inside the headers object.

```
return {
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Look, this is my graph.module.ts
I had the same problem, but fixed with this code:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
// Apollo
import { ApolloModule, Apollo } from 'apollo-angular';
import { HttpLinkModule, HttpLink } from 'apollo-angular-link-http';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { AppConfig } from '../app/app.config';
import { setContext } from 'apollo-link-context';
import { ApolloLink, concat } from 'apollo-link';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';

// GraphiQL: https://launchpad.graphql.com/1jzxrj179


@NgModule({
  exports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    ApolloModule,
    HttpLinkModule
  ]
})
export class GraphQLModule {
  constructor(
    apollo: Apollo,
    httpLink: HttpLink
  ) {
  const http = httpLink.create({uri: AppConfig.apiEndPointGraph});
    // create Apollo

    let token = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjM3LCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vemV1cy1zdGFnaW5nLWVudi51cy13ZXN0LTIuZWxhc3RpY2JlYW5zdGFsay5jb20vYXBpL2FwcC1sb2dpbiIsImlhdCI6MTUyNjQyMjQ4NCwiZXhwIjoxNTI3NjMyMDg0LCJuYmYiOjE1MjY0MjI0ODQsImp0aSI6IkhOMmRPQ2xJeklDVlhpODAifQ.9U4Gxqxeuir5mUvgVgE4FxYgwrGIHvnjCqxWRuHXfUM";

        const authMiddleware = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
          // add the authorization to the headers
          operation.setContext({
            headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
          });

          return forward(operation);
        });
    apollo.create({
      link:concat(authMiddleware, http),
      cache: new InMemoryCache()
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but might help someone:

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { setContext } from 'apollo-link-context';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ApolloModule, APOLLO_OPTIONS } from 'apollo-angular';
import { HttpLinkModule, HttpLink } from 'apollo-angular-link-http';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';

const uri = 'http://yourURI/graphql'; 

export function createApollo(httpLink: HttpLink) {

  const auth = setContext((_, { headers = new HttpHeaders() }) => {
    // get the authentication token from local storage if it exists
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (!token) {
      return {};
    } else {
      return {
        headers: headers.append('Authorization', `${token}`)
      };
    }
  });

  const http = httpLink.create({ uri });

  return {
    link: auth.concat(http),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  };
}

@NgModule({
  exports: [ApolloModule, HttpLinkModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APOLLO_OPTIONS,
      useFactory: createApollo,
      deps: [HttpLink],
    },
  ],
})
export class GraphQLModule { }
```

Remember, the above contents should be in the `graphql.module.ts` that was created for you. If you created it yourself, then you know what tweaks to do then.